# Struggling with a regular expression for a route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using React Router 4. I have only one Component (for now), and I basically would like the route to match this:

```
/
/home
/@prd78
```

In the case of the third one, I would like the part after the @ to become a parameter.

I have tried this, but it is obviously wrong:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/|home|product|@:ref(\w+)/" component={App} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

I could have different routes but in that case, the app would be loaded as many times.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route exact path="/" component={App} />
<Route path="/home" component={App} />
<Route path="/@:ref" component={App} />
```

And then access them using:

```
const App = ({ match }) => (
    <div>
        <p>Ref: {match.params.ref}</p>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: That's what I mentioned I can't do, by using 3 routes like this, the component is also loaded 3 times, so I can't do that.

Comment: Have you tried using `exact`? The component shouldn't be loaded three times.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't change anything. This is all so weird. With Angular 2+, for example, this works out of the box. React Router seems very complicated to achieve such a simple operation :(

Comment: I've tested it and it works as expected, are you certain you've implemented it correctly?

Comment: I believe so :( Also, technically, "exact" has nothing to do with the fact a component will only be loaded once.

 I actually removed react-router from my project entirely and switch to "history" and I handle the routing myself in a Redux action: much less code, better performance, easier to read, no higher-order functions anymore, etc :)